# Keeping class state valid vs performance

Tags: c#, oop, concept

If i have public method that returns a reference type value, which is private field in the current class, do i need to return a copy of it? In my case i need to return List, but this method is called very often and my list holds ~100 items. The point is that if i return the same variable, everybody can modify it, but if i return a copy, the performance will degrade. In my case im trying to generate sudoku table, which is not fast procedure.
Internal class SudokuTable holds the values with their possible values. Public class SudokuGame handles UI requests and generates/solves SudokuTable. Is it good practice to chose performance instead OOP principles? If someone wants to make another library using my SudokuTable class, he wont be aware that he can brake its state with modifying the List that it returns.

Comment: I'd suggest you to show the code of the properties and access methods  you've written so far in order to make your problem easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance and object-oriented programming are not mutually exclusive - your code can be object-oriented and perform badly, etc.

In the case you state here I don't think it would be wise to allow external parts edit the internal state of a thing, so I would return an array or ReadOnlyCollection of the entries (it could be a potential possibility to use an ObservableCollection and monitor for tampering out-of-bounds, and 'handling' that accordingly (say, with an exception or something) - unsure how desirable this would be).

From there, you might consider how you expose access to these entries, trying to minimise the need for callers to get the full collection when all they need is to look up and return a specific one.

It's worth noting that an uneditable collection doesn't necessarily mean the state cannot be altered, either; if the entries are represented by a reference type rather than a value type then returning an entry leaves *that* open to tampering (potentially, depending on the class definition), so you might be better off with structs for the entry types.

At length, this, without a concrete example of where you're having problems, is a bit subjective and theoretical at the moment. Have you tried restricting the collection? And if so, how was the performance? Where were the issues? And so on.

Comment: A useful new thing that was put out via NuGet is the new [`Immutable Collections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace. A `ReadOnlyCollection` guarantees that recipient can not change it, but it could be modified by the creator who has access to the underlying collection. A `ImmutableList` can't be modified once it is created (but you can still add and remove from it, it just creates new lists (it shares internal state between the lists so the new lists do not take up very much memory)).